# Alias not shown in Manual

Tags: powershell-4.0, manual

I add an alias to my PowerShell module, but it is not shown in `Get-Help`.
Here is an MWE:

```
#Require -Version 4.0
function global:Test-Syntax {
    <#
    .Synopsis
        Cmdlet tests ValidateSet
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    # parameter check
    param (
        [ValidateSet("one", "two", "three")]
        [string]$testparam
    )
    Write-Verbose "`$testparam: $testparam"
}
```

After that I define an alias in my profile:

```
New-Alias tstsyn Test-Syntax
```

`Get-Help Test-Syntax` doesn't show the alias.

In contrast: When I define the alias `gh` for `Get-Help` it is shown:

```
...
ALIASE
    gh
...
```

Why are aliase in my own modules not shown in `Get-Help`?